# ASP .NET core missing startup.cs - how to do Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am working on a MVC project (.NET core) and i need to do dependency injection, to inject som interfaces to my controllers.
I realize that i have no startup.cs (that i am used to in older projects).

How do i register a service?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, I don't think that's a .NET core project. That's the old ASP.NET 4.x template.

As for DI in ASP.NET Core see the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: You might be right... Give me a minute.